# PHP getting session username

Tags: php, session

Im trying to get the username of the logged in user from session. I can alert roomnumber and id of the user, but not the username.

Code for storing:

```
session_start();
$con = DbConnect();
if (isset($_POST)) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];                        
$sql = 'select id, username, password, roomNr from room where username = "' .$username. '"';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$userData = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if ($count == 1) {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION["sess_id"] = $userData['id'];
    $_SESSION["sess_username"] = $userData['username'];
    $_SESSION["sess_room"] = $userData['roomNr'];
    session_write_close();
    header("location: ../main_page.php");
} else {
    header('index.php');
}
```

Code for retrieving:

```
echo $_SESSION['sess_username'];
```

NOTE: This is just a quick test to see if i can get the spesific problem working. I am not going to use the above code in the final product.

Solution: The problem wasn't with the php, it had to do with how i used the variable in the script tag.

The working solution:

```
var user = '<?php echo $_SESSION['sess_username']; ?>';
```

Comment: Make sure you have `session_start();` at the beginning of both your pages and check if `$userData['username']` does contain a value.

Comment: Where do you get the variable `$username`? That's probably the most important thing, and is not represented here.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger I do have session_start(); on both. And as pointed out, i can alert both id and room the same way.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, i have edited my question to include what you were asking about

Comment: You need to see if `$userData['username']` has any data in it when you save it to the `$_SESSION["sess_username"]` object.

Comment: ??? I thought you're looking for the logged in user. What is coming through `$_POST`?  Your code as it is now will set any user to whatever username is passed in the POST (unless you're hiding the part about hashing the input password and passing it into the query)

Comment: Now is the time to learn how to use [`prepare()/execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) in MySQLi to protect yourself from SQL injection (which will allow any user to login to this script with ease) [Many good examples are here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski This is just a quick test, i haden't intended to use this code as it is now:)

Comment: Can you not do a combination of the above with maybe into a control of some sorts: <script language="Javascript"> 
var someValue = <?= $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] ?> 
</script>

Comment: @AnthonyHorne Tried, unfortunately it didn't work either

Comment: If you cannot, then why not just store the username with the session on login and thereafter just refer to the username (via the session in the db).  If the session expires, then they must log in again.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne Haven't got much experience with php, but i'll try look it up. Thanks

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept one of the answers, instead of adding 'SOLVED' to the question's title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What my suggestion is, assign your user data to a session array and retrieve. that would not loose your data

```
     session_start();
     session_regenerate_id();
     $_SESSION["user_data"] = $userData;
     session_write_close();
```

And also make sure you are including `session_start()` in all your include files.

Comment: Not quit sure i understood you. How can i get the spesific value of the username this way?

Comment: after you assign the data print and see `$_SESSION["user_data"]`

Comment: This is printed out: testfunction Array()[native code]}

Answer (score 0):

try this to alert with javascript

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{$_SESSION['sess_id']} - {$_SESSION['sess_room']}');</script>";
```

or only to show with php

```
echo "{$_SESSION['sess_id']} - {$_SESSION['sess_room']}";
```

Comment: I have, and it works, it's just the sess_username that dosen't :)

Comment: Well, it didn't work. As i said, the problem is i can't get the ['sess_username'], the ['sess_id'] and ['sess_room'] isn't the problem

Comment: try a `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see what have registered on $_SESSION.

Comment: It dosen't print anything, i guess that's bad?